# Max suffix of a list

Tags: algorithm

This problem is trying to find the lexicographical max suffix of a given list.

---

Suppose we have an array/list [e1;e2;e3;e4;e5].

Then all suffixes of [e1;e2;e3;e4;e5] are:

[e1;e2;e3;e4;e5]
[e2;e3;e4;e5]
[e3;e4;e5]
[e4;e5]
[e5]

Then our goal is to find the lexicographical max one among the above **5** lists.

---

for example, all suffixes of [1;2;3;1;0] are

[1;2;3;1;0]
[2;3;1;0]
[3;1;0]
[1;0]
[0].

The lexicographical max suffix is `[3;1;0]` from above example.

---

The straightforward algorithm is just to compare all suffixes one by one and always record the max. The time complexity is `O(n^2)` as comparing two lists need `O(n)`.

However, the desired time complexity is **O(n) and no suffix tree (no suffix array either)** should be used.

*please note that elements in the list may not be distinct*

Comment: Why don't you ask our friends of [Maths Stack](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: can you explain `lexicographical max suffix`? it seems you just have to take the sublist starting at the maximum element in the list.

Comment: @UmNyobe lexicographical is by dictionary order. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order. Yes, it will start from max element, but what if there are multiple max elements? I mean the elements in the list may not be distinct.

Comment: @Samoth Because it's an algorithm question (more appropriate for [so])?

Comment: @Samoth the only question for you is **why?** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm)

Comment: @JacksonTale `In mathematics and computer science, an algo[...]` so it belongs to both of them. I was thinking that they would be more efficients than us...

Comment: Feels quite similar to the O(n) [Booth's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) if you stick a dummy character on the end and reverse the direction of the comparison operations.

Comment: @Samoth in this case, stackoverflow won't have any algorithm questions, will it?

Comment: @JacksonTale I guess you're right :)

Comment: @Samoth sorry man, i was just joking. It is just many algorithms may need math, but from my mind, math is more theoretical for problems and algorithm is more practical and need programming. that's why i normally put it here

Comment: You might consider http://cs.stackexchange.com since this isn't specifically a 'software algorithm'. Not attempting to start another diatribe on most appropriate stack exchange, just a suggestion :).

Comment: @JacksonTale no problem ;) I was thinking the other way due to my old teachers

Comment: Hm, no suffix tree. What about [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)? [Here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=627379&start=0&mc=37) you can find good explanation of it.

Comment: @Baurzhan suffix array need a suffix tree to easily get O(n)

Comment: @JacksonTate My recollection is that you can't construct suffix trees for alphabets of unbounded size (as is the case here), suffix trees can't be built in time O(n); it takes time O(n log n) in the worst-case. Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: @JacksonTale Are the array elements necessarily integers? If so, is there a bound on their size?

Comment: I've thought about this for a while and have come up with an O(n log n) solution. It's better than the O(n^2) naive solution, but still not down to O(n). Should I post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int max_suffix(const vector<int> &a) 
{
  int n = a.size(), 
      i = 0, 
      j = 1, 
      k;

  while (j < n) 
  {
    for (k = 0; j + k < n && a[i + k] == a[j + k]; ++k);

    if (j + k == n) break;

    (a[i + k] < a[j + k] ? i : j) += k + 1;

    if (i == j) 
        ++j;
    else if (i > j) 
         swap(i, j);
  }
  return i;
}
```

My solution is a little modification of the solution to the problem [Minimum Rotations](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MINMOVE/).

In the above code, each time it step into the loop, it's keeped that `i < j`, and all `a[p...n] (0<=p<j && p!=i)` are not the max suffix. Then in order to decide which of `a[i...n]` and `a[j...n]` is less lexicographical, use the for-loop to find the least `k` that make `a[i+k]!=a[j+k]`, then update `i` and `j` according to `k`.

We can skip `k` elements for `i` or `j`, and still keep it true that all `a[p...n] (0<=p<j && p!=i)` are not the max suffix. For example, if `a[i+k]<a[j+k]`, then `a[i+p...n](0<=p<=k)` is not max suffix, since `a[j+p...n]` is lexicographically greater than it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine in a two player game, two opponents A and B work against each other, on finding the max suffix of a given string s. Whoever first finds the max suffix will win the game. In the first round, A picks suffix s[i..], and B picks suffix s[j..].

```
i: _____X
j: _____Y
Matched length = k
```

A judge compares two suffixes and finds there is mismatch after k comparisons, as shown in the fig above.

Without the loss of generality, we assume X > Y, then B is lost in this round. So he has to pick a different suffix in order to (possibly) beat A in next round. If B is smart, he will not pick any suffix starting at position j, j + 1, ..., j + k, because s[j..] is already beaten by s[i..] and he knows s[j+1..] will be beaten by s[i+1..], and s[j+2..] will be beaten by s[i+2..] and so on. So B should pick suffix S[j + k + 1..] for next round. One extra observation is that B should not pick the same suffix as A either because the first person who finds the max suffix wins the game. If j + k + 1 happens to be equal to i, B should skip to the next position.

Finally, after many rounds, either A or B will run out choices and lose the game, because the number of choices are limited for both A and B, and some choices will be eliminated after each round. 
When this happens, the current suffix that the winner holds is the max suffix (Remember the loser runs out all choices. A choice is given up because either it cannot possibly be max suffix, or it is currently held by the other person. So the only reason that the loser gives up the actual max suffix in some round is that his opponent is holding it. Once a player holds max suffix, he will never lose and give it up).

The program below in C++ is almost literal translation of this game.

```
int maxSuffix(const std::string& s) {
    std::size_t i = 0, j = 1, k;
    while (i < s.size() && j < s.size()) {
        for (k = 0; i + k < s.size() && j + k < s.size() && s[i + k] == s[j +k]; ++k) { } //judge

        if (j + k >= s.size()) return i; //B is finally lost
        if (i + k >= s.size()) return j; //A is finally lost

        if (s[i + k] > s[j + k]) { //B is lost in this round so he needs a new choice
            j = j + k + 1;
            if (j == i) ++j;
        } else {                   //A is lost in this round so he needs a new choice
            i = i + k + 1;
            if (i == j) ++i;
        }
    }
    return j >= s.size() ? i : j;
}
```

Running time analysis: Initially each player has n choices. After each round, the judge makes k comparisons, and at least k possible choices are eliminated from either A or B. So the total number of comparisons are bounded by 2n when the game is over.

The discussion above is in the context of string, but it should work with minor modification on any container that supports sequential access only.