# Search the longest substring in two strings

Tags: c, algorithm

The task is this: Find the longest substring found in two lines. The peculiarity of the problem is that these lines are very long (contents of the file, that is to 400,000 characters each), and the alphabet from which they are composed of short - 4 characters.

Strings can be of different length.

I invented and implemented the following algorithm:

1. To get the contents of the first file and write to a string str1, removing the line breaks
2. To get the contents of the second file and write to a string str2, removing the line breaks
3. We shall consider all substrings the string str1, from the longest to the shortest. To do this, define the cycle while (i>0), at each iteration, which after the main content decreases the length of the string by one. And so to the strings of length 1.
4. Inside the while loop: All substring of length N differ only in the beginning position.

Let have a string of length N:

- It is one substring of length N, which contains, starting at position 0.
- There are two substring of length N-1 that start inside positions 0 and 1
- In it for three substring of length N-2, which starts inside positions 0, 1, and 2

...

- K+1 substring of length N-K, which start from the position 0,1,...,K

The starting position of the count in the for loop(z=0; z<=g-i; z++), within which the function is called getSubstring receiving the substring. And then running the standard function strstr with this substring of a string str2

But does this algorithm long enough. Is there no way to make it faster?

**P.S.** Write in C

Comment: Looks like some school or college task.. is it?

Comment: @SambhavSharma: Yes, it is. It school/college task

Comment: Have a Look at the `diff` implementation on your Computer or the longest Common subsequence Algorithm in Case you really need to Produce Code. as the Problem bears similarity to DNA maTching, a textbook on bioinformatics might help as well.

Comment: Have you had a look at Dynamic programming? If not, have a look at this implementation: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/

Comment: Or maybe this one, this is similar to the above: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-4-longest-common-subsequence/

Comment: @SambhavSharma The first one is too slow, the second one addresses a different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two classical options to solve longest common substring efficiently

- Build a generalized [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_array) or suffix tree of the two strings. One can show that the LCS is a prefix of two adjacent suffixes in the suffix array that have different colors (belong to the different strings). I [once wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220150/rank-the-suffix-of-a-list/21342145#21342145) that describes a simple O(n log n) suffix array construction algorithm
- Build a suffix automaton of one string and feed the other string into it. At every point check how "deep" you are in the automaton and report the maximum over all those depths. You can [find a C++ implementation](https://github.com/niklasb/contest-algos/blob/master/suffix_automaton.cpp) in my GitHub.