# Filter list of strings, ignoring substrings of other items

Tags: python, string, algorithm

How can I filter through a list which containing strings and substrings to return only the longest strings. (If any item in the list is a substring of another, return only the longer string.)

I have this function. Is there a faster way?

```
def filterSublist(lst):
    uniq = lst
    for elem in lst:
        uniq = [x for x in uniq if (x == elem) or (x not in elem)]
    return uniq

lst = ["a", "abc", "b", "d", "xy", "xyz"]
print filterSublist(lst)

> ['abc', 'd', 'xyz']
> Function time: 0.000011
```

Comment: In your example do you need to filter out "yz" string? If you need to make sure only that no filtered string is prefix of another one, then you can use  prefix tree(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_tree) to solve this problem

Comment: How many strings do you have and what is the average length of the elements in `lst`?

Comment: @Vladimir If that were the case, then `b` should be part of the output, but it's not

Comment: @NiklasB. indeed, my bad

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova I've added a linear time solution for this.

Answer (score 8):

A simple quadratic time solution would be this:

```
res = []
n = len(lst)
for i in xrange(n):
    if not any(i != j and lst[i] in lst[j] for j in xrange(n)):
        res.append(lst[i])
```

But we can do much better:

Let `$` be a character that does not appear in any of your strings and has a lower value than all your actual characters.

Let `S` be the concatenation of all your strings, with `$` in between. In your example, `S = a$abc$b$d$xy$xyz`.

You can build the [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of `S` in linear time. You can also use a much simpler O(n log^2 n) construction algorithm that I described [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220150/rank-the-suffix-of-a-list).

Now for every string in `lst`, check if it occurs in the suffix array exactly once. You can do two binary searches to find the locations of the substring, they form a contiguous range in the suffix array. If the string occurs more than once, you remove it.

With LCP information precomputed, this can be done in linear time as well.

Example O(n log^2 n) implementation, adapted from [my suffix array answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21342145/916657):

```
def findFirst(lo, hi, pred):
  """ Find the first i in range(lo, hi) with pred(i) == True.
  Requires pred to be a monotone. If there is no such i, return hi. """
  while lo < hi:
    mid = (lo + hi) // 2
    if pred(mid): hi = mid;
    else: lo = mid + 1
  return lo

# uses the algorithm described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21342145/916657
class SuffixArray(object):
  def __init__(self, s):
    """ build the suffix array of s in O(n log^2 n) where n = len(s). """
    n = len(s)
    log2 = 0
    while (1<<log2) < n:
      log2 += 1
    rank = [[0]*n for _ in xrange(log2)]
    for i in xrange(n):
      rank[0][i] = s[i]
    L = [0]*n
    for step in xrange(1, log2):
      length = 1 << step
      for i in xrange(n):
        L[i] = (rank[step - 1][i],
                rank[step - 1][i + length // 2] if i + length // 2 < n else -1,
                i)
      L.sort()
      for i in xrange(n):
        rank[step][L[i][2]] = \
          rank[step][L[i - 1][2]] if i > 0 and L[i][:2] == L[i-1][:2] else i
    self.log2 = log2
    self.rank = rank
    self.sa = [l[2] for l in L]
    self.s = s
    self.rev = [0]*n
    for i, j in enumerate(self.sa):
      self.rev[j] = i

  def lcp(self, x, y):
    """ compute the longest common prefix of s[x:] and s[y:] in O(log n). """
    n = len(self.s)
    if x == y:
      return n - x
    ret = 0
    for k in xrange(self.log2 - 1, -1, -1):
      if x >= n or y >= n:
        break
      if self.rank[k][x] == self.rank[k][y]:
        x += 1<<k
        y += 1<<k
        ret += 1<<k
    return ret

  def compareSubstrings(self, x, lx, y, ly):
    """ compare substrings s[x:x+lx] and s[y:y+yl] in O(log n). """
    l = min((self.lcp(x, y), lx, ly))
    if l == lx == ly: return 0
    if l == lx: return -1
    if l == ly: return 1
    return cmp(self.s[x + l], self.s[y + l])

  def count(self, x, l):
    """ count occurences of substring s[x:x+l] in O(log n). """
    n = len(self.s)
    cs = self.compareSubstrings
    lo = findFirst(0, n, lambda i: cs(self.sa[i], min(l, n - self.sa[i]), x, l) >= 0)
    hi = findFirst(0, n, lambda i: cs(self.sa[i], min(l, n - self.sa[i]), x, l) > 0)
    return hi - lo

  def debug(self):
    """ print the suffix array for debugging purposes. """
    for i, j in enumerate(self.sa):
      print str(i).ljust(4), self.s[j:], self.lcp(self.sa[i], self.sa[i-1]) if i >0 else "n/a"

def filterSublist(lst):
  splitter = "\x00"
  s = splitter.join(lst) + splitter
  sa = SuffixArray(s)
  res = []
  offset = 0
  for x in lst:
    if sa.count(offset, len(x)) == 1:
      res.append(x)
    offset += len(x) + 1
  return res
```

However, the interpretation overhead likely causes this to be slower than the O(n^2) approaches unless `S` is really large (in the order of 10^5 characters or more).

Comment: Thanks! But for list of 30 elements quadratic time solution would give `Function time: 0.000122` while func in my example gives `Function time: 0.000081`

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova Well you certainly don't care about inputs of that size do you? I was thinking more about the cases where you have thousands of strings. If that's not the case, then why do you worry about performance at all? What's the kind of scale you're interested in?

Comment: I've got a lot of files and I don't know how long the end list will be, so it can be as 100 elements or 10000 elements also (but not so frequently)

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova So what's wrong with your original code then? How have you determined that it is too slow? Also if you want to compare the performance of different approaches, use real data (and not a list with 10 elements, that tells you nothing about what happens for n = 10000)

Comment: @NiklasB. BTW, there is a linear solution if you limit the size of each string in the list. If you're interested check out my answer.

Comment: @bcorso Hm? My solution is already linear (the SA can be built in linear time, and the second step can be performed in linear time as well, although that's a bit less obvious)

Comment: @NiklasB., ah, well I certainly didn't try to digest the entire code because it seems complicated -- I was judging from your statement "Example O(n log^2 n) implementation, adapted from my suffix array answer:" that it was not linear but O(n log^2 n), no?

Comment: @bcorso I'm mentioning in the answer that both steps can be done in O(n) as well (where n is the sum of sizes of all lists). The code is O(n log^2 n) though

Comment: @NiklasB. I see -- so you decided to leave out the code for the `O(n)` solution because it is more complicated? If so, maybe I didn't waste my time with my solution because it seems quite simple and gives `O(n)` for the special case of bounded word lengths.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your problem in matrix form as:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array(["a", "abc", "b", "d", "xy", "xyz"], object)
out = np.zeros((len(lst), len(lst)), dtype=int)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        out[i,j] = lst[i] in lst[j]
```

from where you get `out` as:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

then, the answer will be the indices of `lst` where the sum of `òut` along the columns is `1` (the string is only in itself):

```
lst[out.sum(axis=1)==1]
#array(['abc', 'd', 'xyz'], dtype=object)
```

---

EDIT:
You can do it much more efficiently with:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from string import find

size = len(lst)
a = np.char.array(lst)
a2 = np.char.array(as_strided(a, shape=(size, size),
                                 strides=(a.strides[0], 0)))

out = find(a2, a)
out[out==0] = 1
out[out==-1] = 0
print a[out.sum(axis=0)==1]
# chararray(['abc', 'd', 'xyz'], dtype='|S3')

a[out.sum(axis=0)==1]
```

Comment: What does it give you to build up the matrix instead of just counting inside the inner loop? Then you would at least not use Omega(n^2) space

Answer (score 2):

Does the order matter? If not,

```
a = ["a", "abc", "b", "d", "xy", "xyz"]

a.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
n = len(a)

for i in range(n - 1):
    if a[i]:
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if a[j] in a[i]:
                a[j] = ''


print filter(len, a)  # ['abc', 'xyz', 'd']
```

Not very efficient, but simple.

Comment: If the string `"bc"` is added to the initial list, will this algorithm filter it out?

Answer (score 1):

### O(n) solution:

```
import collections
def filterSublist1(words):
    longest = collections.defaultdict(str)
    for word in words:                                 # O(n)
        for i in range(1, len(word)+1):                # O(k)
            for j in range(len(word) - i + 1):         # O(k)
                subword = word[j:j+i]                  # O(1)
                if len(longest[subword]) < len(word):  # O(1)
                    longest[subword] = word            # O(1)

    return list(set(longest.values()))                 # O(n)
                                                       # Total: O(nk²)
```

---

### Explanation:

To understand the time complexity, I've given an upper bound for the complexity at each line in the above code. The bottleneck occurs at the for loops where because they are nested the overall time complexity will be **`O(nk²)`**,  where `n` is the number of words in the list and `k` is the length of the average/longest word (e.g. in the above code `n = 6` and `k = 3`). However, assuming that the words are not arbitrarily long strings, we can bound `k` by some small value -- e.g. `k=5`  if we consider the [average word length in the english dictionary](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average%20english%20word%20length). Therefore, because `k` is bounded by a value, it is not included in the time complexity, and we get the running time to be **`O(n)`**. Of course, the size of `k` will add to the constant factor, especially if `k` is not smaller than `n`. For the English dictionary, this would mean that when `n >> k² = 25` you would start to see better results than with other algorithms (see the graph below).

The algorithm works by mapping each unique subword to the longest string that contains that subword. So for example, `'xyz'` would lookup `longest['x']`, `longest['y']`, `longest['z']`, `longest['xy']`, `longest['yz']`, and `longest['xyz']` and set them all equal to `'xyz'`. When this is done for every word in the list, `longest.keys()` will be a set of all unique subwords of all words, and `longest.values()` will be a list of only the words that are not subwords of other words. Finally,  `longest.values()` can contain duplicates, so they are  removed by wrapping in `set`.

### Visualizing Time Complexity

Below I've tested the algorithm above (along with your original algorithm) to show that this solution is indeed **`O(n)`** when using English words. I've tested this using `timeit` on a [list of up to 69000 English words](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/wordlist). I've labeled this algorithm `filterSublist1` and your original algorithm `filterSublist2`.

[image]

The plot is shown on a log-log axis, meaning that the time complexity of the algorithm for this input set is given by the slope of the lines. For `filterSublist1` the slope is ~1 meaning it is `O(n1)` and for `filterSublist2` the slope is ~2 meaning it is `O(n2)`.

NOTE: I'm missing the `filterSublist2()` time for 69000 words because I didnt feel like waiting.

Comment: ah, you're right it doesn't work for this case. hmm, okay i'll think on this.

Comment: My bad, the example would actually work correctly. What if `lst = ['abb', 'ba']` though? I believe the whole approach is faulty, because  the character multisets of two strings don't tell you enough about their substring relationship

Comment: Thanks @NiklasB. I wasn't considering substrings on the initial post. I've updated to include substrings making this `O(nk²)` which is still `O(n)` for bounded `k`. Feel free to find more faults with the code by playing with the Ideone example: https://ideone.com/buFm0G