# Clean list of strings that are included on the own strings

Tags: python, string, bash, list, shell

I have a text-file, `lists.txt`, that looks like this:

```
HI family what are u doing ?
HI Family
what are
Channel 5 is very cheap
Channel 5 is
Channel 5 is very
Pokemon
The best Pokemon is Pikachu
```

I want to clean it up, removing any lines that are completely included inside other lines. That is, I want something like this:

```
HI family, what are u doing ?
The best Pokemon is Pikachu
Channel 5 is very cheap
```

I have try with count the large of the strings and later comparate its with grep, finding the sorts results.txt on large results.txt, but it's little effective.

Comment: A very similar, if not the same question has been asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868093/filter-list-of-strings-from-substrings/

Comment: The strings are from .txt file . Im try to do any similar to
if [ grep -q ^$1 schemas.txt ]
then
        echo "Schema already exists. Please try again"
        exit 1
else
        echo "$@" >> schemas.txt
fi

But the problem is that the string always will be included on the second list because the string, ( the father o the son) always are incluided, this get false positives.

Sorry my english

Comment: @user3684326 Split off your input files and commands/scripts in code blocks. Question is not very clear as written.

Comment: I submitted an edit to fix the sample data so it's actually valid. I'm afraid I can't figure out what the last sentence means, or I'd fix it too....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to take a list of strings and remove from it any strings that are substrings of other strings in the list.

In pseudo-code,

```
outer: for string s in l
    for string s2 in l
        if s substringOf s2
            continue outer
    print s
```

i.e. loop through the strings once for every string, canceling each run of the outer loop if any of the tests in its inner loop matches.

Here's an implementation of that algorithm in bash. Note that the file (`list.txt`) is being read through the redirection operator `<` twice in the code, once for the outer loop and once for the inner.

(I've also cleaned up your example, which had a lot of typos.)

```
$ cat list.txt
HI family what are u doin?
HI family what are
Channel 5 is very cheap
Channel 5 is
Channel 5 is very
Pokemon
The best Pokemon is Pikachu
$ while read line; do while read line2; do [[ $line2 != $line ]] && [[ $line2 == *$line* ]] && continue 2; done <list.txt; echo "$line"; done <list.txt
HI family what are u doin?
Channel 5 is very cheap
The best Pokemon is Pikachu
$
```